# Mac App: Push Notifications Arriving, but Not Showing Up in Notification Center

Tags: macos, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I have a question about push notifications on macOS. I am successfully getting notifications in my Mac app (I can see them hit `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in my app delegate). But **nothing actually shows up in Notification Center**.

The same notification shows up fine in my iOS version of the same app, so I'm pretty sure my push notification is formed correctly.

With macOS, do I have to take the content of the push and `deliver` it in order for it to show up?

On iOS, I just have to form the push notification with certain parameters and it will be delivered as a visible push notification (as opposed to a silent background notification). I'm wondering if the same isn't true for macOS (10.13).

Here's my app delegate code:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
      NSUserNotificationCenter.default.delegate = self
  }

  func application(_ application: NSApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [String : Any]) {
    let dict = userInfo as! [String: NSObject]
    let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: dict)

    if let sub = notification.subscriptionID{
      print("Notification: \(sub)") //<-- This fires every time a notification arrives
    }
  }

  //Make sure the notification shows up even if the app is active
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, shouldPresent notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  //??? - Do I need something like this? - ???
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, didDeliver notification: NSUserNotification) {
    NSUserNotificationCenter.default.deliver(notification)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when I was registering for notifications, I was doing this:

```
NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [])
```

This allowed the silent background notifications to come in, but I was omitting the alert types that allow user push notifications to arrive.

**This fixed it:**

```
NSApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.alert, .sound, .badge])
```